# how to append a matrix to the end of another matrix? (using Boost Libraries in C++)

Tags: c++, boost

I have this:

```
  using namespace boost::numeric::ublas;
    matrix<double> m (3, 2);

    int k = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < m.size1 (); j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < m.size2 (); i++)
            m (j, i) = k++;
    }

   m =
     0 1 
     2 3
     4 5
```

And I need to append another matrix m2 to m

```
 matrix<double> m2 (3, 1);
k = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < m2.size2 (); i++)
    m (i, 0) = k++;

m2 = 
  0
  1
  2
```

So, what I need to do to have this

```
  m =
         0 1 0
         2 3 1 
         4 5 2
```

Where can I find more information about operations like this? I ask because the information on http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm resembles more like an API, and it has not been so useful so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is not elegant, but is my first try:

```
m.resize(m.size1(), m.size2()+1, true);
column(m, m.size2()) = column(m2, 0);
```

and, of course it needs to be adjusted if m2 has more than one column (or if there are differences in size1 between the two matrices)

Comment: Is the `column` custom function?